# I tried to use a place holder instead of concatenation, but the code is not running correctly

Tags: c#

```
using System;
namespace justPractice
{
    class program
    {
        static void Main()
        {                      
            Console.WriteLine("how do you feel?");
            string feeling = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(feeling,  "{0} is a good sign");
            Console.ReadLine();                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be: 'Console.WriteLine("{0} is a good sign", feeling);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your parameter orders in `WriteLine` method.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} is a good sign", feeling);
```

From documentation;

```
public static void WriteLine(
    string format,
    object arg0
)
```

and

> format: A composite format string (see Remarks).
>
> arg0: An object to write using format.